# Image is not displaying

Tags: image, wordpress, timthumb

Image is not displaying in wordpress

```
<img src="http://test.schools.com/wp-content/themes/ovid/timthumb.php?src=http://test.schools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/amla.png&amp;h=130&amp;w=200&amp;zc=1" alt="" class="img_nofade" width="200" height="130">
```

After clicking the image, fancy-box contains image.

```
<img id="fancybox-img" src="http://test.schools.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/amla.png" alt="amla">
```

In console, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)"

As i am new to wordpress, can any one give me a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Have you recently changed servers? Your host may have restricted access to the /cache and /tmp folders of the PHP extension on their server. Trust me I'm going through the same thing right now with a free host.

This article explains it more in detail:

http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/tip-for-timthumb-thumb-php-not-generating-thumbnails/

From my understanding the TimThumb plugin needs full read and write privileges to those folders (that's where it stores the thumbs I'm assuming).

I found this out today because I tried transferring from my localhost to an actual free hosting service which restricts those folders (and some functions that TimThumb uses).

In any case I'm almost certain it is a hosting issue when it boils down to it.

FYI: TimThumb is known to be outdated and subject to DoS attacks by hackers. This link will show you the plugin to update the outdated TimThumb plugin (when you get it working obviously) http://www.210consulting.com/wordpress-plugins/securing-your-custom-wordpress-site/

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: I faced same issues. I tired calling the same sript on browser like 
http://localhost/PhpProject2/timthumb.php?src=imag/chain.jpg 
and then it threw certain exception that it cant create certain file. 
used chmod 755 folder and bam, everything working